# What's happened to this zucchini?

Tags: zucchini

I have been growing an Italian sourced zucchini called *Zucchino Romanesco* in a brand new no-dig raised bed, and I have been getting quite large plants and fruits

[image: Zucchini plant]

though the ones pictured are looking a bit odd since I've been away so have not been able to water regularly

[image: zucchinis]

But one of the plants has spread out of the raised bed and is now growing on the lawn.  And I'm now seeing globular fruit.

[image: globular fruit]

[image: more globular fruit]

I've never seen that happen before and am wondering what exactly is happening!

Comment: This last one seems pumpkin, and like pumping you can eat as zucchini, when they are small and green. Pumping growth also larger, so for me it is just wrong seed in the packing. But because they are similar species (biologically) it could be a hybrid, or just water stress activated other genes.

Comment: Pumpkin and zucchini on the same plant?

Comment: No, I understood that "one of the plant".  And the position of fruit seems very different from the photos. (but maybe because I'm used of both plants, and these really seems two different plants)

Comment: it's all growing from the same plant.

Comment: It doesn't say that in the question, it says one of the plants has grown over the lawn....

Comment: Did you purchase the plant? If so, it might have been grafted onto another rootstock. The pumpkin type might be growing out of the rootstock.

Answer (score 1):

Likely just a random seed or plant in what you bought, assuming it's not the same plant that's producing the normal shaped zucchini - there are round zucchinis http://www.condorseed.com/vegetables/squash-summer/squash-round-zucchini/ so perhaps one of those got mixed in with the others. If its the same plant producing both types of zucchini, then some genetic blip has occurred, but round or long, they're still zucchini, which are just a variety of squash.

Comment: I've traced the stem back to a single plant producing normal shaped zucchinis.  And I planted these myself from a grow bag so I know it's not two seeds!  I guess it's just one of those things where one stem has decided to go mutant.

Comment: I'll update if I see the globes develop the typical striations of a zucchini.

Comment: Bear in mind that round zucchini come in varying shades of green, some striped, some not. I wonder what round zucchini taste like, never eaten one

Comment: Looks like I need to save some seeds

Comment: might not be worth it unless you're sure what pollinated yours...